# Terminal applications don't cover the entire terminal

Tags: terminal, configuration, emacs, awesome, alacritty

I've been researching this for a couple hours so far and I can't seem to find a solution that works and isn't 10 years old so I figured I'd ask again.

I'm using `awesome` and `Alacritty`, and when I use, for example, `emacs` in the terminal, the `emacs` theme doesn't cover the entirety of the terminal.
I'm fairly sure that the issue has something to do with `alacritty` resizing based on characters instead of pixels or something like that, but I can't seem to fix it.

I've tried change the gaps in `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua`, I've tried changing font sizes in `rc.lua`, `alacritty.yml`, and in `emacs`, all with varying degrees of success.
I've also tried installing `i3`, and testing on that, because my main pc runs `i3` and doesn't have this issue at all, but that doesn't change anything.

All help is appreciated.[image: Look closely at the bottom of the terminal window, you'll see a dark grey bar. That's the issue I'm talking about.]

Look closely at the bottom of the terminal window, you'll see a dark grey bar. That's the issue I'm talking about.

Comment: What do you expect to happen there? Terminal emulation works on a whole number of character cells. There's no way the terminal could tell your emacs that it has e.g. 37.6 rows and 129.2 columns, and there's nothing emacs could do to paint that 0.6 character row and 0.2 character column.

Comment: If you only care about the single solid color that fills that unused area, the OSC 11 escape sequence should change that (at least in some terminals, not sure about alacritty), e.g. `printf '\e]11;#abcdef\e\\'`. Hook it up somehow to emacs, and reset (OSC 111 with no `;` and color parameter) upon quitting.

Comment: I didn't expect it to cooperate immediately but I figured the solution would a be a bit more straight forward. It's just strange to me why the terminal on my desktop (QTerminal, which also tried and to no avail) works without configuration while my other machine is so problematic. Thank you for the help though, I'll be sure to try it out.